# Infer tuple from const array of numbers?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

*I'm having troubles finding correct keywords to express what I'm looking for; feel free to edit my title so it makes more sense.*

I'd like to know if it's possible with TypeScript to achieve something like the below "pseudo-TS"?

It doesn't work, but I wish it did behave as I say in the comments:

```
type Constraint<T extends number> = {    // T => 3 | 4 ?
  [k in T]: { min: number, max: number }
}

type Data<K extends number[] = []> = {  // is there anyway to use `Data` *without* its param by 
  indexes: K,                          // asking TS to infer K from `indexes`?
  constraints: Constraint<typeof K>
}

const d: Data = {            // Data<3 | 4> is inferred from indexes
  indexes: [3, 4],           // being given a const array `[3, 4]`
  constraints: {
    3: { min: 0, max: 120 },
    4: { min: 10, max: 20 },
    10: { min: -3, max: 3},  // -> Would error, since 10 is not in `indexes: [3, 4]`
  }
}
```

There are a lot of missing pieces for me there, and as I said, not knowing which terms to search for, I'm having trouble deciding whether it's definitely not feasible...

Since everything in what I want to do stems from the *value* of the `indexes` array, I'm guessing it shouldn't be possible. But I have seen things such as:

```
[1, 2, 3] as const // => 1 | 2 | 3
```

so I wonder if that could be used in my situation in any way?

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/Ymprbw) what you're looking for?  If so I can write it up as an answer; if not, please elaborate.

Comment: ah damn, that's smart! Yes it is what I'm looking for, even though I couldn't have imagined an identity function would be part of the solution. After reading tens of TS answers/explanations from you on SO over the last 3 weeks, I'm glad you found my question! Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

this may help you solve problem

```
type Constraint<T extends number> = {    // T => 3 | 4 ?
  [k in T]: { min: number, max: number }
}

type Data<T extends ReadonlyArray<number>, K extends number> = {  // is there anyway to use `Data` *without* its param by 
  indexes: T,                          // asking TS to infer K from `indexes`?
  constraints: Constraint<K>
}

const indexesNum =  [3, 4] as const ;

type GetItem<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer I> ? I: never;

const d: Data<typeof indexesNum, GetItem<typeof indexesNum>> = {            // Data<3 | 4> is inferred from indexes
  indexes: indexesNum,           // being given a const array `[3, 4]`
  constraints: {
    3: { min: 0, max: 120 },
    4: { min: 10, max: 20 },
    10: { min: -3, max: 3},  // -> Would error, since 10 is not in `indexes: [3, 4]`
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @marindelophy, thanks for the help! It does work, which is a great improvement on my own attempts, and you definitely taught me a few new tricks I didn't know yet; however I'm looking for a simpler solution, if it exists, where `Data` where things can be inferred strictly from the value of `indexes`, without having to define it beforehand and use it as params of the `Data` type.